# Find the limit as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ of $\frac{\sin(x)(1-\cos(y))}{6xy^{2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, limits-without-lhopital

I used the path $y=x$ and got that the limit equals $12$. How do I manipulate the original expression to prove that the limit actually equals $12$ for all paths? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!! To write math expressions you have to use $\mathrm\LaTeX$ and, to render it, you have to ouse MathJax.

Comment: The limit is not $12$ but $1/12$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for the original limit. We have $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sin x(1-\cos y)}{6xy^2}=\frac16\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\underbrace{\frac{\sin x}x}_{\text{$1$ (remar-}\\\text{kable limit)}}\underbrace{\frac{1-\cos y}{y^2}}_{\{0/0\}\;(1)},$$ where in $(1)$ we can use [this helpful answer (Finding the limit of $(1−\cos x)/x^2$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1334183/525384), so $$\lim_{y\to0}\frac{1-\cos y}{y^2}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{(1-\cos y)(1+\cos y)}{y^2(1+\cos y)}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\sin^2y}{y^2}\frac1{1+\cos y}=\frac12.\tag*{(*)}\label{(*)}$$ Hence, the original limit can be written as $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sin x(1-\cos y)}{6xy^2}=\frac161\frac12=\frac1{12}.$$

$\ref{(*)}$ Thank you [egreg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/62967/egreg) to mention an easier solution!

Comment: Note that the question is tagged limits-without-lhopital.

Comment: @Christoph whoops, thank you so much for pointing it out!

Comment: It is simpler if you multiply numerator and denominator by $1+\cos y$. :-)

Comment: @egreg make an answer and teach me $\ddot\smile$. You are right!

Comment: @manooooh It's in the same answer you quote!

Comment: @egerg lol, yes! Please look at the edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

@manooh

Computing the limit of $(1-\cos x)/x^2$ without l'Hopital's rule is easy:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {1 - \cos x} {x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac {1 - (1 - 1/2x^2 + \mathcal o(x^3))} {x^2} = \frac 1 2 + \lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\mathcal o (x^3)}{x^2} = \frac 1 2
$$

Comment: Good approach! Please do not make an answer just to remark something to a user; instead, make a comment or post a new complete answer.