# Finding the limit of an expression without the use of L'Hopital

Tags: calculus

I have the following question:

> Calculate the $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{x}$

So to begin I rewrote it as:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2\sin^2(x)}{x}$$

& I'm wondering whether it would be acceptable to use the small-angle approximation for sine here since the limit tends towards 0 so it would fit the description. However if anyone has an alternative method that doesn't require any approximation I'd love to hear it. Thank you.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you not allowed to use $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\sin x}x = 1$?

Comment: Hi player3236 I re-read the notes just to make sure and it appears that we're able to use this, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your way is fine and by [standard limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/75130/505767) we can conclude indeed

$$\frac{2\sin^2(x)}{x}= 2\cdot \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2 \cdot x \to 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 0 =0$$

as an alternative by [standard limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1334164/505767) again

$$\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{x}=4x\cdot\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{(2x)^2} \to 0 \cdot \frac1 2=0$$

Answer (score 4):

Because $|\sin(x)|\leq |x|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, you have
$$\left|\frac{2\sin^2(x)}{x} \right| \leq 2|\sin(x)|$$

so you can conclude by squeeze theorem.