# This limit is puzzling me

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am solving a question which involves finding the continuity of a piece-wise function at a particular point, and it involves finding the below limit:$$\lim_{{x \to 0}} \frac{{\tan x - \sin x}}{{x^3}}$$

Now, my solving was to write $\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ instead of $\tan x$ and I finally got on to: $$\lim_{{x\to 0}}\frac{\sin x(1-\cos x)}{x^3\cos x}$$

Then I split it further as: $$\lim_{{x\to 0}}\frac{\sin x}{x}\times \lim_{{x \to 0}}\frac{(1-\cos x)}{x^2}\times\lim_{{x \to 0}}(\sec x)$$

The central term is bothering me.

L' Hopital would work fine, but I don't learn L' Hopital in school - it's only for the entrance examinations. Expansions are also not taught.

How do I proceed now?

Comment: Expansions are also not taught.

Comment: Please see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334164/finding-the-limit-of-1-cos-x-x2?noredirect=1). The limit $\lim (1-\cos x)/x^2$ is well-known and can be treated with $\lim \sin x/x$.

Comment: $1 - \cos x = 2(\sin\frac{x}{2})^2$.